# Spring Boot issue with AWS SES authentication

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ses

I have a Spring Boot app where on some occasions I am sending automated emails. My App is hosted on AWS ECS(Fargate) and is using AWS SES for sending emails. I added a role to my Fargate task with all needed permissions for AWS SES. Most of the time, the app is able to authenticate and send emails correctly however on some occasions authentication fails and because of that email/s are not sent. The error I am receiving is:

```
> Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain:
> EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials
> from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and
> AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)),
> SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials
> from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey),
> WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the
> aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path.,
> com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@6fa01606:
> profile file cannot be null,
> com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@4ca2c1d:
> Failed to connect to service endpoint
```

Now, if this would happen each time I would conclude that I configured something incorrectly. However, since authentication fails only sometimes I am not sure what the problem is.

I am using the following aws-sdk version: 1.12.197
When I am initializing a client, I am doing it on the following way:

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard() .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Does anyone has any idea why authentication would fail only sometimes?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I’d add some logging before/after the exception, ideally with the contents of those env variables to see if there’d any environmental difference between the containers. That wont solve the problem but might help troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that one of my ECS tasks used an older version of the Task definition and it didn't have the correct permissions set. After I updated it, it seems to work fine no.